Maximizing $\tfrac{(u^T v)^2}{u^T(I + A)u} + \tfrac{(u^T v)^2}{u^T(I + B)u}$
Let $A, B$ denote two positive semidefinite matrices and $v$ a nonzero vector.
What is the value of
$$
\sup_{u \neq 0} \Big\{\frac{(u^T v)^2}{u^T(I + A)u} + \frac{(u^T v)^2}{u^T(I + B)u}\Big\}?
$$
In the case $A = B$, this can be calculated by Cauchy-Schwarz: $2 v^T(I + A)^{-1} v$. However, I cannot see how to handle $A \neq B$.

Have you tried using Lagrange multiplier with the constraint $u^Tu = 1$? Is the resulting equation solvable for $u$?

Your problem is a special case for the paper that @whpowell96 shared.
Based on the optimality condition (3.2) therein, you can simply design a fixed-point algorithm to find a local solution.
Or, check out a parametric approach proposed here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/5237
Maybe another approach:
Let $x = (I+A)^{1/2}u,\, y = (I+B)^{1/2}u$
$$
\frac{(u^T v)^2}{u^T(I + A)u} + \frac{(u^T v)^2}{u^T(I + B)u} = \frac{x^TPx}{\|x\|^2}+\frac{y^TQy}{\|y\|^2},
$$
where $P=(I+A)^{-1/2}vv^T(I+A)^{-1/2},\, Q=(I+B)^{-1/2}vv^T(I+B)^{-1/2}$.
The problem becomes:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sup_{x,y} \Bigg\{\frac{x^TPx}{\|x\|^2}+\frac{y^TQy}{\|y\|^2}\Bigg\} \\
&s.t.\,\, (I+A)^{-1/2}x= (I+B)^{-1/2}y
\end{align*}
$$
Then use block coordinate descent between variables $x$ and $y$.

Again, this is not so helpful. Why should my problem be as difficult as the general case in that paper? Here, we have a simplification: the parameters $B = W$ in their paper.

Here is a paper that addresses this problem. It appears to be much more nonlinear than is suggested by the $A=B$ case and optimality conditions take the form of a nonlinear eigenvalues problem, shown in Theorem 3.2 of the linked paper.
Lei-Hong Zhang. "On optimizing the sum of the Rayleigh quotient and the generalized Rayleigh quotient on the unit sphere".

In their notation, my problem is less general, since it has (again, using their notation) $B = W$. Hence, we could hope for something more explicit in this case.

"The paper includes consideration of the special case where the matrices in the numerators are scalar multiples of teacher other"---where? Note that $D = \mu W$ is not the two matrices in the numerator (one is the denominator, and the other is the numerator).

Ah, I got my notation confused between the post and the paper. From a bit more searching through the literature, it seems that the nonlinear eigenvalue problem is the only known method for this problem as stated, but perhaps some of the work simplifies if the matrix in the numerator is rank one as in your case. This property remains true even after transforming into the form from the paper

$
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}  \def\g{\gamma}  \def\l{\lambda}
\def\aa#1{\a^{#1}}
\def\bb#1{\b^{#1}}
\def\gg#1{\g^{#1}}
\def\ll#1{\l^{#1}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\q{\quad}     \def\qq{\qquad}  \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracBR#1#2{\BR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, re-define $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$ to absorb that pesky $I$ matrix (making them positive definite)
and define the following scalar variables
$$\eqalign{
\a &= u^TAu &\qiq \grad{\a}u = 2Au \\
\b &= u^TBu &\qiq \grad{\b}u = 2Bu \\
\g &= v^Tu  &\qiq \grad{\g}u = v \\
}$$
Write the objective function and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \frac{\gg2}{\a} + \frac{\gg2}{\b} \\
\grad{\phi}u
 &= \frac{2\g v}{\a} + \frac{2\g v}{\b}
  - \frac{2\gg2Au}{\aa2}   - \frac{2\gg2Bu}{\bb2} \\
}$$
Formally solve the $\sf zero\ gradient$ condition for $u$
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\frac{2\gg2A}{\aa2} + \frac{2\gg2B}{\bb2}} u
  &= \LR{\frac{2\g}{\a} + \frac{2\g}{\b}} v \\
\LR{\frac{A}{\aa2} + \frac{B}{\bb2}} u
 &= \fracLR{\a+\b}{\a\b\g} v \\
u &= \fracLR{\a+\b}{\a\b\g}\LR{\frac{A}{\aa2}+\frac{B}{\bb2}}^{-1}v
}$$
Since the scalars $\lbrace\a,\b,\g\rbrace$ on the RHS depend on $u$,
this is not really a solution, however it suggests the following iterative solution method
$$\eqalign{
&u = {\sf random\ unit\ vector} \\
&{\sf do} \\
&\q w = u \\
&\q \a = u^TAu,\q \b = u^TBu \\
&\q u = \LR{\frac{A}{\aa2}+\frac{B}{\bb2}}^{-1}v \\
&\q u = \frac{u}{\|u\|} \\
&{\sf until}\;\ \|u-w\|\le10^{-12} \\
}$$
which is reminiscent of power iteration for eigenvalue problems.
